# looping over rows in a table and checking inputs

Tags: javascript, visualforce

I have a page that a user can dynamically add rows to a table.  Each row contains 3 input fields.  I need to loop over each row in the table (1:n rows) and I need to check the input values in each row.

The input fields on each row are as follows: contactName, userName, accountName

For each row, here is the check I'm trying to do.

if the contactName is not null (has a value) then I want to set the image icon for userName and accountName to "display: none"

if the userName is not null (has a value) then I want to set the image icon for contactName and accountName to "display: none"

If the accountName is not null (has a value) then I want to set the image icon for contactName and username to "display: none"

So, basically, if one of the inputs has a value, then I want to hide the image icon for the other two input fields.

The one catch, is the contactName and accountName field can both be populated.  In that scenario, I want to hide the image icon for the accountName.

I started creating the function to loop over the table rows using the following:

```
function checkParticipantRows() {
    alert("We are inside the checkParticipant Rows function");
    var table = document.getElementById('{!$Component.theForm.participantBlock.participantSection.participantTable}');
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        alert("We are looping over row number " + i);
        var cells = table.rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var x=0; x < cells.length; x++) {
            alert("We are looping over the rows input fields");
            alert(cells[x].getAttribute("value"));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm stuck on how I can check the inputs?  How can I reference the inputs in each row?  The input ids are dynamically generated.  Is there a way to reference the inputs directly by the row and then check the values?

I've included some raw html from the page source for the table that has 4 rows that were dynamically generated.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `table.rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")`

Comment: _"if the contactName is not null (has a value)"_ - None of the inputs will ever be null: if nothing is entered the value will be an empty string. _"I've included some raw html from the page source"_ - No you haven't. Please update your question to show the html.

Comment: @Pointy that code is something from that *visualforce* framework?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown no "getElementsByTagName" is a native DOM method that's been around forever.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for your reply.  I am a bit closer and looping over the inputs, but it seems my looping is incorrect.  See the modified code above.  I start by looping over the number of rows and then have an inner loop where I loop over the inputs, but it loops over all rows first, then it loops over all the inputs.  It should enter the first row loop and then iterate over the inputs on that row.  Then start the iteration of the second row, etc.

Comment: @Dman100 that code should be pretty close. One tip: use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`; it's way less of a pain. The messages show up in the browser developer console. Also, you don't have to use `.getAttribute()` for the "value" - just reference it as a property of the DOM element: `console.log(cells[x].value);`

Comment: Instad of checking for "value", did you try "checked"?